# How to play audio locally on regex match while tailing logs on ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

I am tailing a log through SSH and would like it to play a sound on my local machine whenever a line matches a regex, so I get "alerted" when there's an error.

I was thinking of a combination of tail > sed > aplay but I have no idea how to choose where each command will execute when in an SSH session.

How do I play audio locally when a tail in an SSH session matches a regex?

**Note:** No changes can be made to the remote.

Comment: [Have you tried using the bell?](https://serverfault.com/questions/500839/let-the-local-machine-beep-when-some-event-happen-on-remote)

Comment: Wouldn't that play the sound on the remote?

**Edit:** It doesn't even play a sound when I run `echo -en "\007"` locally anyway.

Comment: No offense, but the question I linked to asks the same thing. Did you read it?

Comment: I commented and then started reading into more details. But as stated in the edit, no sound locally with the bell. I'm using a laptop so I'm not even sure it has a PC speaker. **Edit:** I also tried `echo -e '\a'` as the other answer stated. **Edit2:** Okay, I found the bell option in the terminal and it works.

Comment: Okay so far I have a working solution with the bell but it's not perfect. First, the bell sound happens on several cues like when erasing nothing in the terminal. That could cause me to miss an error or try to find an inexistent one. Second, it plays the same sound no matter which one of the logs I tail has an error. Is there any way to run a command locally in a script? I know it's possible with <enter>~ but that's not an option AFAIK.